# Как из словаря вывести 3 ключа с максимальным значением?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть словарь, из которого надо вывести 3 максимальных значения. Как это можно реализовать?

```py
di = {'Матерь Богов': 528, 
        'Крылья': 162, 
        'Эта Музыка Будет Вечной': 295, 
        'Золотое пятно': 1567, 
        'Утро Полины': 174}
```

У меня получается вывести только одно максимальное значение вот таким кодом:

```py
ma = (max(di, key=di.get))
print(ma)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
di = {
        'Матерь Богов': 528,
        'Крылья': 162,
        'Эта Музыка Будет Вечной': 295,
        'Золотое пятно': 15,
        'Утро Полины': 174
      }

di2 = di

for i in range(3):
    ma = (max(di2, key=di2.get))
    print(ma)
    di2.pop(max(di2, key=di2.get), 3000)
```

Answer (score 6):

Используйте сортировку и срез. Поскольку сортировка идёт в возрастающем порядке, нужно брать три последних элемента:

```py
print(sorted(di, key=di.get)[-3:])
```

Вывод:

```
['Эта Музыка Будет Вечной', 'Матерь Богов', 'Золотое пятно']
```

Answer (score 1):

[heapq.nlargest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) решает именно эту задачу:

```
import heapq

di = {'Матерь Богов': 528, 
        'Крылья': 162, 
        'Эта Музыка Будет Вечной': 295, 
        'Золотое пятно': 1567, 
        'Утро Полины': 174}

print(heapq.nlargest(3, di, key=di.get))
```

> ```
> $ python nlargest.py
> ['Золотое пятно', 'Матерь Богов', 'Эта Музыка Будет Вечной']
> ```